# Upserting a value at an array position using $min

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I would like to either insert a new document with a default value as part of an array, or update that part of the array if the document already exists.

What I thought of was:

```
db.test.update(
    { "a": 5 },
    { $setOnInsert: { "b": [0, 0] }, $min: { "b.0": 5 } },
    { upsert: true }
);
```

If I do that, then I get:

> Cannot update 'b' and 'b.0' at the same time

Another idea was to remove `$setOnInsert` and just keep `$min`, since the minimum between nothing and `5` should be `5`.

```
db.test.update(
    { "a": 5 },
    { $min: { "b.0": 5 } },
    { upsert: true }
);
```

This doesn't raise an error, but now the document I get is:

```
{ "a" : 5, "b" : { "0" : 5 } }
```

I need an array with `5` at position `0` however, not an object with a `0` property.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.bulkWrite()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/) for this, and it's actually a prime use case of why this exists. It only sends "one" actual request to the server and has only one response. It's still two operations, but they are more or less tied together and generally atomic anyway:

```
db.junk.bulkWrite([
  { "updateOne": {
    "filter": { "a": 1 },
    "update": { "$setOnInsert": { "b": [ 5,0 ] } },
    "upsert": true
  }},
  { "updateOne": {
    "filter": { "a": 1 },
    "update": { "$min": { "b.0": 5 } }
  }}
])
```

Run for the first time will give you an "upsert", note that it's "inserted" and not "modified" in the response:

```
{
        "acknowledged" : true,
        "deletedCount" : 0,
        "insertedCount" : 0,
        "matchedCount" : 1,
        "upsertedCount" : 1,
        "insertedIds" : {

        },
        "upsertedIds" : {
                "0" : ObjectId("5947c412d6eb0b7d6ac37f09")
        }
}
```

And the document of course looks like:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5947c412d6eb0b7d6ac37f09"),
        "a" : 1,
        "b" : [
                5,
                0
        ]
}
```

Then run with a different value to [`$min`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/min/) as you likely would in real cases:

```
db.junk.bulkWrite([
  { "updateOne": {
    "filter": { "a": 1 },
    "update": { "$setOnInsert": { "b": [ 5,0 ] } },
    "upsert": true
  }},
  { "updateOne": {
    "filter": { "a": 1 },
    "update": { "$min": { "b.0": 3 } }
  }}
])
```

And the response:

```
{
        "acknowledged" : true,
        "deletedCount" : 0,
        "insertedCount" : 0,
        "matchedCount" : 2,
        "upsertedCount" : 0,
        "insertedIds" : {

        },
        "upsertedIds" : {

        }
}
```

Which "matched" `2` but of course [`$setOnInsert`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/) does not apply, so the result is:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5947c412d6eb0b7d6ac37f09"),
        "a" : 1,
        "b" : [
                3,
                0
        ]
}
```

Just like it should be

Comment: Are the operations guaranteed to be atomic though? I'm concerned that another query targeting the `{ "a": 1 }` document might be able to run between the first `updateOne` and the second `updateOne` in the `bulkWrite` batch.

Comment: @rid It's as atomic as it's going to get, and certainly better than issuing "two requests" and needing to await responses. Is it possible under extremely high workloads? Well without digging deep on the source I won't discount the possibility. But is that highly unlikely? Then the latter question's response is Yes, and it's likely you would never see this happen. These are a batch of transactions after-all and MongoDB does need to track them, particularly as an "ordered" operation, which is the default. Moreover, it's not like there is a better alternative.

Comment: @rid Moreover I think you a missing the point that with "IF" ( big IF intended ) some other operation actually submitted in between then it should not be a problem. The `$min` would make sure than any value here such as `4` were submitted then it would be a valid write, and then be subsequently overwritten by `3` as intended. Anything with a larger value than the default or last modification would simply be ignored. So this is actually the recommended way to do this. You cannot write to the  same path with different or same operators in the same operation.

Comment: Thanks, this is an elegant solution.